# Deploy SSDT package via VSTS and cannot Drop objects?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am successfully deploying an SSDT package in my VSTS release. If publishing directly from Visual Studio, there is a flag **"drop_objects_not_in_source"** under advanced settings.   However, cannot figure out how introduce this in my CI/CD pipeline.  There are a bunch of refactoring tools but none address this.   So, I am stuck with object on the sql server that have been deleted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the command line argument `/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true` when publishing the database or use a publish profile that contains the setting.